# Idiom / expression to tell someone to not overthink something

Tags: expressions, idioms, idiom-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-meaning

Something like : “go to your head”

Thank you

Comment: "Don't overthink it!"

Comment: There is an expression [**go to someone's head**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/go_to_someone's_head) but its meanings are not about over-thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good one:

> Don't allow yourself to get trapped by the paralysis of analysis!

Comment: Analysis paralysis...! Where did I hear this?

Comment: @RamPillai: Possibly you heard it or read it in a motivational speech or motivational book. I've heard the saying in a number of contexts, including how to grow a business by taking chances and not overthinking things. Psychologists in general are probably well versed in this all-too-common human phenomenon.